# Bootstrap 3 - Removing padding/margin on small devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Framework Bootstrap 3 and have trouble with the layout on f.e. iPad in portrait mode (in general small devices). 
How can i remove the margin / padding on the left and right side?
When i look this page on iPad there should be no space left and right.

I have tried many things:

```
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Above CSS-code causes still a margin on the right side!?

I've created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bBc8c/28/

Can somebody help?
Regards

Comment: Do you have [`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) (or similar) in your `<head>` (no pun intended)?

Comment: Yes, what i have: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Bootstrap default `container` class for example..

```
<div class="col-md-12 container>
<div class="header">some text here</div>
<p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

the container will adjust padding for you...

Comment: i've tried this, bute there is still a (maybe 2-3pxl) space on the left?

Comment: To remove the reaming space use custom css, like...
.space{padding-left:5px;}